# Estimation of conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

Let we have random variables $\left(X_1, X_2, .., X_n \right)$ with pmf $p(X)=\theta(1-\theta)^x; x=0,1,2,\ldots\quad  \mathrm{and}\quad 0<\theta<1$

I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}\Big[ I[X_1=0] \Big| \sum_i X_i = t \Big]$

In my textbook direct solution given as $\frac{n-1}{t+n-1} \qquad (n\geq2)$.

Can you please suggest some approach how to estimate this. I have general idea on how to estimate `expectation`, but could not get how can I proceed with this expectation.

Comment: This is just the conditional probability $P(X_1=0\mid \sum X_i=t)$ which can be readily simplified. There is no estimation involved in this particular calculation, unless it is the estimation of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_iX_i$ is a [sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) for $\theta$, that is, conditioned on this sum the distribution of the data doesn’t depend on $\theta$. In the present case, all $n$-tuples that sum to $t$ are equiprobable. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), there are $\binom{t+n-1}t$ such tuples. If $X_1=0$, the remaining $n-1$ values have to sum to $t$, and there are $\binom{t+n-2}t$ such tuples. Since all tuples that sum to $t$ are equiprobable, the desired probability is just the ratio

$$
\frac{\binom{t+n-2}t}{\binom{t+n-1}t}=\frac{n-1}{t+n-1}\;.
$$